# SUBSTRING_INDEX em mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho estes valores na tabela da base de dados, onde no campo arrachar a vírgula separa como se fosse uma coluna.
Os dados estão desta forma:

```
Id------arrachar
1       2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço,14,Almoço,12,Almoço_(Dieta),2,Lanche,14,Jantar,10,Jantar_(Dieta),10
2       2018-04-27,Peq_Almoço,15,Almoço,12,Almoço_(Dieta),3,Lanche,15,Jantar,12,Jantar_(Dieta),2
```

Agora pretendo separar cada valor entre vírgulas com o `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.
Tenho este código, onde só está correto a data:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 1) AS `data`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 2) AS `Pequeno Almoço`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 3) AS `Quantidade Peq. Alm.`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 4) AS `Almoço`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 5) AS `Quantidade Almoço`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 6) AS `Lanche`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 7) AS `Quantidade Lanche`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 8) AS `Jantar`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 9) AS `Quantidade Jantar`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 10) AS `Jantar Dieta`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 11) AS `Quantidade Jan. Die.`

FROM centrodb.marcacaoInfancia
```

Resultado:

```
data         Pequeno Almoço          Quantidade Peq. Alm.              Almoço                        ...   ...   ...
2018-04-26  2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço   2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço,14    2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço,14,Almoço
2018-04-27  2018-04-27,Peq_Almoço   2018-04-27,Peq_Almoço,15    2018-04-27,Peq_Almoço,15,Almoço
```

Vou mostrar o problema, no `Pequeno Almoço` só devia ter `Peq_Almoço` e não `2018-04-26,Peq_Almoço`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar assim:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 1) AS `data`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 2), '.', -1) AS `Pequeno Almoço`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 3), '.', -1) AS `Quantidade Peq. Alm.`,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 4), '.', -1) AS `Almoço`,
       ...
```

Comment: Não funciona....coloquei assim `SUBSTRING_INDEX((arrachar, ',', 2), '.', -1) AS ``Pequeno Almoço`,` mas dá este erro `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Existe um pequeno erro de sintaxe aqui: `SUBSTRING_INDEX((arrachar, ',', 2), '.', -1)`. Utilize `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 2), '.', -1)`.

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro? Se sim, verifique a chamada da função *SUBSTRING_INDEX*. Ela espera pelos parâmetros *coluna*, *caracter a ser buscado* e *contador de ocorrências*.
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(*(arrachar, ',', 2)*, ',', -1)`. A seção entre asteriscos é onde está o seu problema.

Comment: Já funcionou, só tem um pequenino erro na sua sintaxe em vez `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 2), '.', -1)` a correta é esta `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ',', 2), ',', -1)`, só muda esta parte `, ',', -1)`, troco o ponto pela vírgula

Answer (score 0):

Não garanto que seja a melhor alternativa, mas não deixa de ser uma:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 1) AS `data`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 1)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 2)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 1)) + 2)) AS `Pequeno Almoço`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 2)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 3)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 2)) + 2)) AS `Quantidade Peq. Alm.`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 3)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 4)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 3)) + 2)) AS `Almoço`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 4)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 5)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 4)) + 2)) AS `Quantidade Almoço`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 5)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 6)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 5)) + 2)) AS `Lanche`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 6)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 7)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 6)) + 2)) AS `Quantidade Lanche`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 7)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 8)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 7)) + 2)) AS `Jantar`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 8)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 9)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 8)) + 2)) AS `Quantidade Jantar`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 9)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 10)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 9)) + 2)) AS `Jantar Dieta`,
SUBSTR(arrachar, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 10)) + 2, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 11)) - (LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(arrachar, ",", 10)) + 2)) AS `Quantidade Jan. Die.`;
```